# Android - SonarQube

Tags: java, android, sonarqube

I am trying to add SonarQube to my application and it compiles fine and I can run ./gradlew SonarQube, which runs. The problems are:

1) I get loads of these:

```
Class 'com/view/widget/feature/features/BaseFeature' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
```

2) It finishes and runs successfully, but I can't see a report being produced.

Below is my SonarQube in my build.gradle:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "GradleAndroidTest"
        property 'sonar.login', 'admin'
        property 'sonar.password', 'admin'
        property "sonar.projectName", "DSB"
        property "sonar.projectVersion", "V1.0"
        property "sonar.language", "java"
        property 'sonar.sourceEncoding', 'UTF-8'
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
        property "sonar.java.binaries","build/intermediates/classes"
        property "sonar.tests", "src/test/java"
        property "sonar.android.lint.report", "build/lint-results.xml"


    }
}
```

Can anyone solve my issues?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue in the past. Managed to solve it with this on my gradle file.

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        def compileDependencies = project.configurations.compile.files.collect {it.path}join(",")
        def compileOnlyDependencies = project.configurations.compileOnly.files.collect {it.path}join(",")

        property "sonar.java.libraries", "$compileDependencies,$compileOnlyDependencies"
        property "sonar.test.libraries", "$compileDependencies,$compileOnlyDependencies"

    }
}
```

Regards,

Comment: I then get the following error:

Could not find property 'compileOnly' on configuration container.

Was compileOnly added separately?

Comment: @JamesKing have you tried to invoke Sonar from the Android Studio's gradle runner? 
Invoke Sonar via the sonar-runner Gradle plugin, which will take care of setting the above properties (plus sonar.libraries and others) for you.

Comment: And I think this limitation relates to the following Jira ticket that should be fixed in the next 2.1 version of the Gradle plugin for SonarQube: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGRADL-6